# Can't set UILabel Text Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In my iOS app, I'm trying to set the text of a UILabel in another view.

I do this by passing a NSNotification to the viewController when it should be updated.  I know it is receiving the message correctly because I log the message, but it just isn't appearing in the UILabel (which I added in the storyboard).

This is my code:

**ProcessingViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *progressMessage;
```

**ProcessingViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateProgressDialog:) name:@"uploadProgress" object:nil];
}

-(void) updateProgressDialog: (NSNotification *) notification{
    NSString *message = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"received updateProgressDialog message of %@", message);
    self.progressMessage.text = message;
    [self.progressMessage setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

My storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Is the `IBOutlet` hooked up? I.e., is `progressMessage` non-`nil`? If `nil`, this can happen either if the `IBOutlet` is not hooked up in Interface Builder or the view controller, itself, was instantiated incorrectly (e.g. `[[ProcessingViewController alloc] init]` rather than `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:...]`).

Comment: @Rob yes and yes. I'm able to log the progressMessage and confirm that it is not nil. also, I hooked up the IBOutlet using the storyboard.  I added an image to show how I connected the IBOutlet.

Comment: Then confirm the `frame` of the `progressMessage`, too. Make sure it's wide enough to show the text. You might want to look at the whole view hierarchy to make sure the frames are correct and that you don't have something in front of the label, obscuring it. E.g., pause execution and type `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at the `(lldb)` prompt. You also can try the somewhat flaky view debugger built into Xcode.

Comment: @rob I moved the label to ensure it wasn't being blocked by the UIImage, but I still don't see it.  I also ensured that static text wasn't checked.  Are there other properties of the uilabel I should be looking for?

Comment: Don't rely on IB. Look at the `frame` when the app is running. Also, I assume you're posting this notification from the main thread?

Comment: @rob yes, the notification is being posted on the main thread. If I put placeholder text in the UILabel, it appears correctly in the app.  I checked to make sure it can always display any text I would send programmatically (no overflow, etc.)

Comment: @Rob yes I log the message and it appears correctly, for example: Uploaded 3/4 images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79209/discussion-between-rob-and-scientiffic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagnosing this offline, we confirmed that this was really being received on a background thread. In that case, you can either post the notification to the main queue, or you can have `updateProgressDialog` dispatch the UI updates to the main queue:

```
-(void) updateProgressDialog: (NSNotification *) notification{
    NSString *message = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"received updateProgressDialog message of %@", message);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.progressMessage.text = message;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i have in mind is you have to viewController and your passing a message from the childViewController to the parentViewController using `NSNotificationCenter` ? Is that cor

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateProgressDialog:) name:@"uploadProgress" object:nil];
 }
```

but if you want to send the message back the message using `NSNotificationCenter`

//childViewController.m

```
 //i tried adding this to your code to test if the `NSNotificationCenter ` responds, and it is responding
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"uploadProgress" object:@"Your message"];
```

while i think what you need to do is to make sure the your update is at the main tread..

```
-(void) updateProgressDialog: (NSNotification *) notification{

    NSString *message = [notification object];

    NSLog(@"received updateProgressDialog message of %@", message);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        self.progressMessage.text = message;
    });
}
```